# extract two fields from distinct values with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is the structure of my data base:

```
 { 
 "_id" : "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
 "risks" : [ 
    {
        "attrib" : "totalWeight", 
           "attribName" :"poids",
        "conditions" : [ 
            {
                "value" : 0,
                "operator" : "!==",
                "min" : "totalWeight",
                "strictComparator" : false,
                "message" : "PTC ou charge utile incorrects !"
            }
        ]
    }, 
  }
```

I want to obtain as a result a list containing distinct `attrib` with its value of `attribName`:

```
{"attrib": "totalWeight", "attribName":"poids"}
```

This query gives me a result composed of empty objects ::

```
aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": "$risks.attrib"}},{"$project":{"_id":0,"id1":"$risks.attrib","text": "$risks.attribName"}}])
```

Comment: because of your aggregation `group` contains only `attrib` you should either `push` data or use `$$ROOT` and then used `project`

Comment: You need to use $unwind on your "risks" array first before performing the grouping.

Comment: `db['auto.SubscribeRules'].aggregate([{ $unwind : "$risks" },{"$group": {"_id": "$risks.attrib"}},{"$project":{"_id":0,"id1":"$risks.attrib","text": "$risks.attribName"}}])` always obtaining the same result: empty objects, even with the push $$ROOT